# Unable to post on tumblr from iOS OAuth1.0, OAConsumer client

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, tumblr

I am trying to integrate "tumblr" into my application.I am able to get the access token successfully. But, when I try to post, I am getting the following error

```
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

I am using the `OAuthConsumer` client for iOS, which I have pulled if from `MGTwitterEngine`.

This is what I have tried.

```
#import "ViewController.h"


#define consumer_key  @"u9iZvT8KIlrTtUrh3vUeXXXXXXXXXXXXXAfgpThGyom8Y6MKKCnU"
#define consumer_secret  @"xfA10mQKmALlpsnrFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
#define request_token_url  @"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token"
#define access_token_url  @"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"
#define authorize_url  @"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%@"
#define base_url @"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.tumblr.com/info"
#define user_info @"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}




- (IBAction)postIt:(id)sender
{

    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/xxxxxxxx.tumblr.com/post"];
    OAMutableURLRequest *oRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:postURL
                                                                    consumer:self.consumer
                                                                       token:self.accessToken
                                                                       realm:nil
                                                           signatureProvider:nil];
    [oRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [oRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    OARequestParameter *statusParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"body"
                                                                         value:@"Sample Body"];
    OARequestParameter *statusParam2 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"type"
                                                                         value:@"text"];

    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:statusParam,statusParam2, nil];
    [oRequest setParameters:params];
    OAAsynchronousDataFetcher *fetcher = [OAAsynchronousDataFetcher asynchronousFetcherWithRequest:oRequest
                                                                                          delegate:self
                                                                                 didFinishSelector:@selector(sendStatusTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                                                                                   didFailSelector:@selector(sendStatusTicket:didFailWithError:)];
    NSLog(@"URL = %@",[oRequest.URL absoluteString]);

    [fetcher start];
}


- (void)didReceiveAccessToken:(OAServiceTicket *)ticker data:(NSData *)responseData
{


}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView*)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error {
    // ERROR!
}




- (void)sendStatusTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticker didFinishWithData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    if (ticker.didSucceed) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
    NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Description = %@",responseBody);


}
- (void)sendStatusTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticker didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    self.consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:consumer_key secret:consumer_secret];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request_token_url];


    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:self.consumer
                                                                      token:nil   // we don't have a Token yet
                                                                      realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                          signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];


}
- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
    if (ticket.didSucceed)
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.accessToken= [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];

        NSURL *author_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:authorize_url,self.accessToken.key]];
        OAMutableURLRequest  *oaR = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:author_url consumer:nil token:nil realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];        
        UIWebView  *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:webView];
        webView.delegate=self;
        [webView loadRequest:oaR];

    }
}

// This is to get oAuth_verifier from the url

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSString *keyOne = @"oauth_token";
    NSString *keyTwo = @"oauth_verifier";
    NSRange r1 =[url rangeOfString:keyOne];
    NSRange r2 =[url rangeOfString:keyTwo];
    if (r1.location!=NSNotFound && r2.location!=NSNotFound) {
        // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
        NSString* verifier = nil;
        NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
            NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"oauth_verifier"]) {
                verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (verifier) {
            NSURL* accessTokenUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"];
            OAMutableURLRequest* accessTokenRequest =[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:accessTokenUrl
                                                                                     consumer:self.consumer
                                                                                        token:self.accessToken
                                                                                        realm:nil
                                                                            signatureProvider:nil];
            OARequestParameter* verifierParam =[[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_verifier" value:verifier];
            [accessTokenRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [accessTokenRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:verifierParam,nil]];
            OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
            [dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:accessTokenRequest
                                     delegate:self
                            didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicketForAuthorization:didFinishWithData:)
                              didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
        } else {
            // ERROR!
        }
        [webView removeFromSuperview];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)requestTokenTicketForAuthorization:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (ticket.didSucceed)
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.accessToken = [self.accessToken initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
        accessText=self.accessToken.key;
        accessSecret=self.accessToken.secret;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response = %@",responseBody);
    }


}
- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}


@end
```

Whats the mistake I am making here? Why I am getting that error? Did I follow the steps properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please XXX out your consumer_key and consumer_secret to avoid unwanted use of them. 
Code wise there are a few things you might want to look for here.

1. Are you able to use an oauth 'GET' request such as "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info"?
   If you can receive a successful 'GET' request then your access token is valid and you can look at how you're sending your post parameters.
2. Make sure you are passing in your parameters as HTTP Body as well as signature parameters. Correct parameter ordering is likely provided by the library.

   NSString *postbody = @"body=myBodyText&type=text";

   [oRequest setHTTPBody:[postbody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:TRUE]];