# Share text on Tumblr from ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, share, tumblr

In my application I want to share text via tumblr api.

I just want some hint on this so I can get exact idea on how to share text on tumblr.

Thanks

Comment: Here you are the hint: Tumblr most certainly has some sort of API documentation - read it and benefit from it.

Comment: @H2CO3 ok thanks for reply. I will check that API document

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627481/unable-to-post-on-tumblr-from-ios-oauth1-0-oaconsumer-client and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591172/how-to-share-text-over-to-tumblr-using-xcode

Comment: @H2CO3, thanks I achieved that :)

Comment: @SS Very good, you're welcome. Have you found something useful?

Comment: @H2CO3 yes I found api for sharing test on Tumblr

Answer (score 0):

You can can use https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK#authentication

i have shared text to tumblr with below code

```
    NSArray* paramsKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"title",
                       @"body",
                       nil];
    NSArray* paramsVals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"Testing",
                       @"HEllo Posting it to Tumblr",
                       nil];
    NSDictionary *paramsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:paramsVals forKeys:paramsKeys];



    [[TMAPIClient sharedInstance]text:@"blogname" parameters:paramsDict callback:^(id response, NSError *error)
    {

        if(!error)
        {
            NSDictionary *dashboard = response;
            NSLog(@"%@",dashboard);

        }
    }];
```